# How to dismiss "Would like to save this password to use with apps and websites?" during execution of UI tests

Tags: swift, passwords, xcuitest

I'm currently using

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System alerts") { alert in
      let notNowButton = alert.buttons["Not Now"]
      if notNowButton.exists {
         notNowButton.tap()
         return true
      }
      return false
 }
```

to dismiss system alerts disaplayed during the execution of ui test but the following "sheet" is not recognized as an alert and I cannot dismiss it.

[image]

I have used the "record" button in xcode to get the ui coordinate of the "Not now" button:

```
app.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Not now"].tap()
```

I face this problem related to the above sheet with Xcode 14.3.
Is there a solution to dismiss these systema "sheets" during the execution?

Comment: Also having this issue. This should be automatically dismissed by the system or Apple should give us a way to turn this off for tests easily.

Answer (score 5):

By the way we solved this problem using the following method:

```
private func eventuallyDismissPasswordAlert(_ app: XCUIApplication) {
   if app.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Non ora"].waitForExistence(timeout: 2) {
       tap(app.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Non ora"])
       return
   }
   if app.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Not Now"].waitForExistence(timeout: 2) {
       tap(app.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Not Now"])
       return
   }
}
```

Comment: If you localize "Not Now" in your UI tests, you shouldn't need two blocks doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on simulator or on a device that doesn't need the feature, you can go to the Settings app and disable filling passwords from the keychain under **Passwords** and **Password Options**. That will keep the sheet from ever popping.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I have not mentioned this solution, but I would like to avoid this solution because is time/credit consuming  since we have more then 900 ui test running on continuos integrations. I should set "Autofill pwd" to false for each UI test.

Comment: Correct Solution.
Additional details providing here,
-if simulator asks for the password when we click on the Passwords Option in settings, give 1234 and it will work